# Redirect Causes: Can't Set Headers After They Are Sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, redirect, nuxt.js

NuxtJS Version 2.8.1

I have used the redirect function on many other pages, this one being a helper page to redirect to the user's last worked page. I dont get any other logged information besides that error, though it does work just fine - I just don't want any caveats happening in the future because this only happens on our Production server.

In my browser when going to the page to redirect me to my last worked page, I get a `302` on this page that redirects me to my respected page with a `304`.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/593) on github that is similar, though it uses the `fetch()` method. One of the contributors said to use `asyncData` like in my case and that is is fixed with the latest version of Nuxtjs back in 2017, but I still get this error.

This is this non-fatal error I'm getting and it only appears on production.

```
 Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
     at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
     at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
     at setHeadersFromObject (/var/www/production/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:94:16)
     at ServerResponse.setWriteHeadHeaders (/var/www/production/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:122:5)
     at ServerResponse.writeHead (/var/www/production/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:30:36)
     at Object.At.o [as next] (server.js:1:0)
     at t.context.t.context.redirect (server.js:1:0)
     at asyncData (ce3f051d30716eaa1dc4.js:1:0)
     at <anonymous>
     at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
```

I think its because NuxtJS isn't 301'ing correctly?

This is the source code that causes this:

```
async asyncData({ $axios, redirect}) {
    var body = await $axios.$get('/user/session/all');
    if(!body 
    || !body.step
    || body.step == 1){
        redirect('/send/photo');
    }

    const is_auth = await $axios.$get("https://my_api.com/Data/Utility/IsAuthenticated/");
    if(!is_auth.isAuthenticated)
        redirect("/send/account");

    var page = "/send/photo";
    switch(body.step){
        case 2:
            page = "/send/video";
            break;
        case 3:
            page = "/send/message";
            break;
        case 4:
            page = "/send/account";
            break;
        case 5:
            page = "/send/recipient";
            break;
        case 6:
            page = "/send/invoice";
            break;
        case 7:
            page = "/send/invoice";
            break;
        case 8:
            page = "/send/review";
            break;
    }

    redirect(page);
},
```

What could it be?

Comment: How/where/when does that function get called? The error basically means that stuff has been written out to the response channel already when your code attempts a `redirect()`.

Comment: its in the `asyncData` function, it gets called before the page is rendered. It's a special nuxtjs method to allow ' server side rendering'

Comment: Right well an arbitrary amount of time can elapse between the `await` statement(s) and what comes later. If other code is writing to the response IO channel, it can definitely happen before the `redirect` calls.

Comment: Not sure you do the best way, perhaps you should handle authentication in nuxtServerInit instead of asyncData...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you pasted redirect will be executed two times. You dont stop flow after u call redirect first time. You should add return after first redirect

```
if(!is_auth.isAuthenticated) {
    redirect("/send/account");
    return
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was it! I was thinking that `redirect` would stop the flow, though I understand now it all makes sense. Thanks again cheers